# Unable to get full string response from SOAP request in Android

Tags: android-ksoap2

I am using ksoap2 to handle SOAP service. My problem is I am able to get small responses string perfectly from Soap Request. When I try to get large data from SOAP Request I am not gettting full response from the service. I am getting some amount of String response only. Can anyone suggest me how can resolve my issues?

The following was the error I got before the I got my response in logact.

```
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d1c478 that was originally bound here
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d1c478 that was originally bound here
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-03 05:54:20.481: E/ActivityThread(701):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701): null
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d1c478 that was originally bound here
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-03 05:54:20.621: E/StrictMode(701):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**Edit1:**

```
06-03 06:09:46.440: W/Trace(1347): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=3980 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeNetworkViolation: policy=31 violation=4
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1123)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:144)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:76)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:146)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at com.example.mytranzz.StopList.onCreate(StopList.java:85)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-03 06:09:46.440: D/StrictMode(1347):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=3818 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeNetworkViolation: policy=31 violation=4
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1123)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.poll(BlockGuardOs.java:117)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:200)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:161)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:76)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:146)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at com.example.mytranzz.StopList.onCreate(StopList.java:85)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=3640 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeNetworkViolation: policy=31 violation=4
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1123)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:573)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:821)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.openInputStream(ServiceConnectionSE.java:113)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:160)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at com.example.mytranzz.StopList.onCreate(StopList.java:85)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-03 06:09:46.451: D/StrictMode(1347):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=1600 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeNetworkViolation: policy=31 violation=4
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1123)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readHeaders(HttpEngine.java:621)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:574)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:821)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.openInputStream(ServiceConnectionSE.java:113)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:160)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at com.example.mytranzz.StopList.onCreate(StopList.java:85)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=1449 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeNetworkViolation: policy=31 violation=4
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1123)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:304)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthInputStream.read(FixedLengthInputStream.java:45)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:176)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at com.example.mytranzz.StopList.onCreate(StopList.java:85)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-03 06:09:46.461: D/StrictMode(1347):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 06:09:46.481: D/dalvikvm(1347): GC_CONCURRENT freed 338K, 13% free 4047K/4600K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 260ms
**strong text**.
```

**Edit2:**

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stoplist);
    getStopsNamesList();

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


    new Thread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run(){

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelop =  new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            soapEnvelop.dotNet = true;
            soapEnvelop.implicitTypes = true;
            soapEnvelop.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC2003;
            soapEnvelop.xsd = SoapEnvelope.XSD;
            soapEnvelop.xsi = SoapEnvelope.XSI;
            soapEnvelop.setAddAdornments(false);

            soapEnvelop.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE (URL);
            System.out.println("Before try catche");

            try
            {
                aht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
                aht.debug = true;

                aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelop);



                 final SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelop.getResponse();
                 String str = response.toString();
                 String strcheck = str;

                 Log.d("WS",strcheck);

                 if (soapEnvelop.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault)
                 {
                        String str1= ((SoapFault) soapEnvelop.bodyIn).faultstring;
                        Log.i("", str1);
                 } 
                 else
                 {
                      SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) soapEnvelop.bodyIn;
                      Log.d("WS", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));

                 } 
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception : " + ex);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
}).start();



    btnSaveStopInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSaveStopInfo);
    btnSaveStopInfo.setOnClickListener(this);

    location = getIntent().getExtras().getString("fromLocation");


    lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,stopsList);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            StopList.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChange(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
 {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // if(position == 1)

            String fromAdapter = adapter.getItem(position);

            selectedStop = fromAdapter;

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you able to confirm that the response sent was actually complete? Like via using fiddler2 or any debugger?

Comment: @aiapatag, I am using console statements. It was not coming fully.

Comment: then the one responding must be the problem, not you.

Comment: @aiapatag, the thing is responding is working fine when I used same service for iPhone application.

Comment: could you try and see the HTTP traffic if the SOAP Response was indeed complete? If yes, then we can rule out that the responder IS NOT the problem.

Comment: I added some errors I got on logcat above. Could you please check and suggest me what is wrong

Comment: @aiapatag, I added my total console after receiving the response in Edit1 above. Could you please check and suggest?

Comment: you can try a number of options below.

Comment: In serveral cases I saw StrictModeNetworkViolation with AndroidBlockGuardPolicy when you are trying to access Ui elements from another thread (maybe in doInBackground() AsyncTask?)

Comment: and  yeah give some time limit. like  HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE (URL,15000); it can be useful too,

Comment: @MitBhatt, still I am facing the same issues

Comment: Which SDk are you using? and on Which OS? is is it Mac or Windows?

Comment: I am using 4.2 Google API with mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first logs, you can try a number of things:

- [Disable "Exchange Services" under Settings > Apps > All](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14592133)
- [Try deleting the Emulator Device then create a new one.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13771952)

Then for the second logs:
(error: `android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeNetworkViolation: policy=31 violation=4`)

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8057833) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11072480). Basically, when doing network calls such as Web Services, **you should do it on a separate thread** rather than doing it on the Main UI Thread.

Comment: Thanks for your continued support. I made the changes as you suggested and now there are no error in my logcat. But the main thing was not yet fixed. That is I am unable to get full response string from SOAP request. Which quite working great in IOS. I can see 1 message is repeating in my logcat. That is "Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0".

Comment: may i reiterate, did you try to invoke the call for the web service (SOAP) on a **separate thread**?

Comment: I used a separate thread and made the changes. I updated by code above (Edit2). Could you please suggest and help me

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the code where you did that? Also, can we try to use [fiddler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7371642)? It's actually free and you can use it on an Android emulator. It's basically a tool where it sniffs/gets packet data transmitted via HTTP in your machine (or a remote machine). From there, we could see if indeed a complete SOAP response is being returned by the responder.

Comment: I edited my question by posting my code above (Edit2). Please have a look into that. And regarding the link is showing page not found error.

Comment: refresh this page and try the link again. its working for me.

Comment: Can I run this on device with out adding this Fiddler?

Comment: You dont need to **add** fiddler. You just need to run it while running your app (in this case, your android emulator). And see if the SOAP response is indeed complete when being returned by the responder.

Comment: Still I am not getting the full response.

Comment: have you tried to see the HTTP traffic using fiddler2? if yes, could you post the response sent by the responder? so we can confirm if it is complete or not?

I won't be able to help you without doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Hiii... For this "Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 problem [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0) may be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks I implemented the filter. But my actual problem is still there.

Comment: It is not your issue,, http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39723, see this. May be you can get help

Comment: this is not the answer to the question. his problem is that he's getting an incomplete SOAP response.